# Meaning and working of a function_f()(variable_v) ( a function followed by variable in () )

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, python-module

I have recently started working with `Keras` and in their documentation, few lines of codes are shown

```
inp = Input(shape=(2,))

hl_x = Dense(4, activation='tanh', name= 'First_Hidden_Layer_Following_Input' )(inp)
```

where

```
type(Input)

>> function

type(inp)

>>>tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor
```

`Input` is a function and `inp` is a variable of type `tensor`

What is the meaning of this and how is it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dense(....)` returns an object, [that can be `__called__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__), similar to a parametrized function:

```
def print_multiple(k):
    """Returns a function that prints 'k' times whatever you give it."""
    return lambda x: print(*(x for _ in range(k)))

print_multiple(6)("Merry")  
print_multiple(4)("Christmas")
```

prints

```
Merry Merry Merry Merry Merry Merry
Christmas Christmas Christmas Christmas
```

[keras.layers.dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/) is a callable object - so along the lines of:

```
class PrintMult:
    """Object that prints 'how_often' times whatever you give it."""
    def __init__(self, how_often):
        self.how_often = how_often

    def __call__(self, what_ever):
        print(*(what_ever for _ in range(self.how_often)))

PrintMult(5)("Yeeha")    # Yeeha Yeeha Yeeha Yeeha Yeeha
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in Keras, but I'll try to highlight it.

First of all, all layers in Keras are callable object, e.g. they define __call__ method. What does it mean? Such classes might be used as a function:

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10,10))
functor = Layer()
res = functor(x)
```

It's not a Keras feature per se, just general Python syntax. Since your object potentially has a longer lifetime in comparison to a function call, you might accumulate some intermediate data inside your object, e.g. a layer could keep all relevant gradients inside.

Secondly, I guess, but I'm not confident, such approach tackles performance issues. When you're defining your model not so many things happens. Actually, you just link inputs and outputs between layers into a directed graph/network... And that's all, nothing more and this is very cheap in terms of computational resources, you just define a structure of your model by passing **inp** and **h1_x** between layers and each layer just registers it as it's own input/output. All the magic and heavy stuff would happen later - during model.compile() and actual training/inference stages.